# Convert web response result with json in dynamic c# array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I get web response in Json format which is following (sample)

```json
{  
   "result":{  
      "Student1":{  
         "Age":"15",
         "School":"ABC"
      },
      "Student2":{  
         "Age":13,
         "School":"XYZ"
      },
      "Student3":{  
         "Age":14,
         "School":"123"
      }
   }
}
```

The result I get for Student1, Student2 and so on is dynamic. Meaning as I send request for students, I will get the response result for those students only.

I want to capture this result in a dynamic way.
I would like to create an array with `key` of students and `value` of Ages so that all the students can be stored as `keys` and Ages as `values` pairs.
Then I want to assign those values to other variables in my application according to key - value pair. For example, wherever student1 exists the value of age should be assigned to that variable.

Comment: Please provide relevant code and a description of what is not working within your code as per StackOverflow recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can student objects be more complex than what you shown in your example or will it always be "name":"value" scenario? Also, is your age really once sent as string `"Age":"15"` and for other student as integer `"Age":13`?

Comment: my apology. student Age is always int. "Age": 15. and yes, student will have only name: value structure always for Age and School.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent [Json.Net library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your JSON.

First, you need to create some classes like this to hold the data.  The dictionary inside the `RootObject` class is needed here since the student keys are dynamic.  The names of the properties inside the classes (`Result`, `Age` and `School`) match to the corresponding property names in the JSON.

```
class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Student> Result { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize the JSON like this (where `json` is your JSON string):

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and access the values like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Student> kvp in root.Result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Age: " + kvp.Value.Age);
    Console.WriteLine("School: " + kvp.Value.School);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Full demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/joEimE